# Ruby on Rails : NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I am a beginner in ROR .I faced a problem that when I test code on one book. I follow it stage by stage, but the error show up...

NoMethodError in CaculatorController#calculate

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Rails.root: /home/toth4321/calculator

```
app/controllers/caculator_controller.rb:4:in `set_charset'
```

**Controller**

```
class CaculatorController < ApplicationController
  before_filter:set_charset
  def set_charset
    @headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=GB2312'
  end

  def calculate
    if request.post?
      arg1 = convert_float(:arg1)
      arg2 = convert_float(:arg2)
      op = convert_operator(:operator)
      @result = op.call(arg1, arg2)
    end
  end

  private
  def convert_float(name)
    Float (params[name])
  end

  def convert_operator(name)
    case params[name]
      when "+" then proc {|a,b| a+b}
      when "-" then proc {|a,b| a-b}
      when "*" then proc {|a,b| a*b}
      when "/" then proc {|a,b| a/b}
    end
  end
end
```

**Views**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>簡單的網頁計算器</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= form_tag(:action => :calculate) %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:arg1, @params[:arg1], :size =>3) %>
      <%= select_tag(:operator, options_for_select(%w{+ - * /})), @params[:operator])) %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:arg2, @params[:arg2], :size =>3) %>
      <%= submit_tag（"送出"）　％>
    <% end_form_tag %>
    <b><%= @result %></b>
  </body>
</html>
```

can somebody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what `@headers` does, but as far as i see, you haven't defined it anywhere. Try:

```
  def set_charset
    @headers = {'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=GB2312'}
  end
```

Comment: it show up this error

`/home/toth4321/calculator/app/controllers/calculator_controller.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
    @headers = ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=GB2312'
                                       `

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@` from `@headers` since it's not an instance variable, but rather a delegate method for the `response.headers` hash:

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=GB2312'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run by adding the following code.

```
before_filter :set_charset
def set_charset
    @headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=GB2312" 
end
```